# How does the function call to reverse the string in the code below?

Tags: python, string, reversing

```
def reverse(s): 
  str = "" 
  for i in s: 
    str = i + str
  return str
  
s = "Geeksforgeeks"
  
print ("The original string  is : ",end="") 
print (s) 
  
print ("The reversed string(using loops) is : ",end="") 
print (reverse(s))
```

I tried the code in my own way to understand how the above method is reversing the string entered in `s` in my own way

i will post what i tried to know where I have gone wrong in my understanding

```
s='preetham'
for i in s:
    str=''
    s=i+str
    print(s)
```

I tried the above code to just understand what role is **i** and **str** playing in helping the code to reverse the string,
as I predicted from my understanding the above code should print the following output

```
p
r
e
e
t
h
a
m
*
```

Comment: Write the variables down on a piece of paper and then execute the code by hand to see how it works.

Comment: Change `str = i + str` to `str = str + i`...What happens then?  An additional tip is to add `print(str)` after the `str = ...` line, to see how the string is being created.

Comment: Your code prints the current letter of the string iteration before an empty string. Doesn't reverse anything or accumulate a larger string

Comment: Besides, the conventional python solution is `return s[::-1]`

Comment: @BruceWayne heyyy that was helpful but still I am confused on what role is str='' playing in reversing.

Comment: @OneCricketeer exactly ''Your code prints the current letter of the string iteration before an empty string. Doesn't reverse anything or accumulate a larger string'' yes that is why I am confused by this answer `return s[::-1]` This is an easy one to understand `return s[::-1]` and I know this works and is easy to understand for me maybe because I know about slicing operations and how negative indexing works. But the first question still confuses me on how it is working.

Comment: You've misplaced your `str=''` inside the loop, so it's effectively doing nothing. When outside the loop, it's adding characters and creating a new, larger `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the output `p r e e t h a m` you should use :

```
s='preetham'
str = ''
for i in s:
    str=str + i + ' '
print(str)
```

**So, What this does?**

First line we store *preetham* in a variable **s**.

Second we initialize a variable **str** with **''**[an empty string] to store the new string

Third we start a for loop.

Here what does the for loop do?
The variable **i** extracts each character[or you may call letter here] of strings one by one and each time executes the code within the loop with each value of i.

Inside the loop:

We append each character[stored in **i**] of  to **str** along with a space [**' '**].

Last line outside the loop we print the value of **str** which is now `p r e e t h a m`

So What happens when we run the program?

First i = 'p' & str = ''
str = '' + 'p' + ' ' [ = 'p ']

Then i = 'r' & str = 'p '
str = 'p ' + 'r' + ' ' [= 'p r ']

...

Finally i = 'm', & str = 'p r e e t h a '
str = 'p r e e t h a ' + 'm' + ' ' [ = 'p r e e t h a m ']

Lastly in print we print str:
p r e e t h a m

So.

```
p
r
e
e
t
h
a
m
```

Will be printed if just use **'\n'** instead of **' '**

Now You can understand the 2 other codes too by this explanation.